# Is it possible to create per-document information management policies (either with native SharePoint or 3rd-party addons)

Tags: workflow, information-management

Is there a way to code/configure or utilise a 3rd-party solution that will enable per-document information management policies?

I have a client requirement whereby they require separate policies "per document". Per-folder or per-content type simply won't do. The process is this:

1. User creates document
2. User fills metadata
3. Event handler fires and based on metadata, a new information management policy is configured

My current thinking is custom workflow is the only way to accomplish the goal as per-document policies are not OOTB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something might be able to be hashed out if you can branch out the documents into child content types.  Perhaps if things are uploaded as a parent content type, then based on the the metadata provided, a workflow could set the content type to the proper child content type and would enforce the IRM policy.

If you think about it, IRM is working on a per document basis, since each document is subject to IRM.  You'd just have to figure out what the retention policies for those documents are, create the proper parent and child content types, and configure a workflow to set things appropriately and let IRM do it's thing.

Comment: Not really the answer I was hoping to get (I wanted a magical answer which provided exactly what I was looking for). However, absent any other suggestions, the above is the most correct (i.e. let the workflow sort it out). Ultimately I think insisting on per-document IRM is the wrong approach.

Comment: Well, not all documents would or should have the same IRM policies, some should stick around longer than others. The only way to do that reliably is to use multiple content types.

Comment: Multiple content-types do go a long way to helping IRM but one CT per document is unmanageable. I suppose it depends upon the use case. Ultimately it seems SharePoint wont support per-item IRM without code/some third-party solution. Thanks for the help.